# In Rails, how can I share a private method to nested controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, nested-resources

I have a resource of `Player` that has various nested resources, such as: `Measurable` and `Workout`.

I have a variable that is used int he Player's header on their pages and it has a variable I need to be set whether I'm accessing an action from the Player_Controller or from one of the other nested resources controllers.  How can I dry up my code to add that variable somewhere so that I don't have to include the same like of code in every controller... as shown below:

**PlayerController**

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_measurable_summary

   #...

   private
     def set_measurable_summary
       @measurable_summary = @player.measurable_summary
     end
end
```

**WorkoutController**

```
class Players::WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_measurable_summary

   #...

   private
     def set_measurable_summary
       @measurable_summary = @player.measurable_summary
     end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily done with a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html):

```
# app/controllers/concerns/measurable_summary.rb

module MeasurableSummary
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_measurable_summary
  end

  private

  def set_measurable_summary
    @measurable_summary = @player.measurable_summary
  end
end
```

Then include it into your controllers:

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  include MeasurableSummary
  ...
end

class Players::WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  include MeasurableSummary
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move that method to `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

  def set_measurable_summary
    @measurable_summary = @player.measurable_summary
  end
end
```

Comment: Only is the right way if this method is used in (nearly) all controllers. Otherwise starting to add shared methods for some controllers inside `ApplicationController` opens door to hell when the codebase grows ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use extend controller to get parent private method. Please do this:

```
class Players::WorkoutsController < PlayersController
end
```